# PCA: Find covariance matrix's eigenvalues: solving a polynomial of degree N

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, pca

If I understand correctly, PCA's principle is very simple:

1. Calculate data vectors' covariance matrix **C**.
2. Solve det(**C** - **e***I) = 0, to find matrix **C**'s eigenvalues **e**.
3. Calculate matrix **C**'s eigenvectors (from those eigenvalues).

**FIRST:** Is this description correct?

**SECOND:** Any algorithm for machine-solving of the polynomial equation det(**C** - **e***I) = 0 ?
I understand that this is a general math question (finding roots of a polynomial of degree **n**).

**THIRD:** Are there any **simple** implementations of PCA in C/C++

Thanks much.

Comment: Two of three of your questions are beyond the scope of this site. You may wish to consider asking the first two questions elsewhere, and restricting this question to PCA implementations.

Comment: Don't solve eigenvalues by root finding the characteristic equation. That won't work as your problems get bigger. Use an eigenvalue solver designed for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all, in order to find eigenvalues there is not need to solve equation you just mentioned. There is such thing as [eigendecomposition of a matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix)
2. Second, the covariance matrix is symmetric and positive semi-definite, so eigendecomposition for this matrix is equal to [singular value decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).
3. For both mentioned decompositions there is a lot of free and proprietary implementations (the state of the art implemenation is [LAPACK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK)).
4. There is a lot of libraries that contains PCA. If commercial implementations are suitable you can try [FinMath from RTMath](https://www.rtmath.net/products/finmath/) or [NMath from CenterSpace](http://www.centerspace.net/products/nmath/) (both for .NET). Otherwise you can try [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/s/gsl/) or some other library (there are several questions on StackOverflow that contains more complete list of numerical libraries).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into the Gnu Science Library (gsl). It provides eigenvalue finding functions. Beware, finding eigenvalues is an iterative, numeric operation; i.e. it is not exact, and it is expensive. I believe gsl uses what is called the QR algorithm.